# VBA / Macro upgraded from 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: excel, vba

I have been upgraded from 32bit to 64 bit and my macro to merge and arrange files in a folder does not work any more, not a VBA user so am pretty much stuck and would appreciate help getting the marco to work ?

```
Option Explicit

 '32-bit API declarations
Declare Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "SHGetPathFromIDListA" (ByVal pidl As Long, ByVal _
pszpath As String) As Long

Declare Function SHBrowseForFolder Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "SHBrowseForFolderA" (lpBrowseInfo As BrowseInfo) _
As Long

Public Type BrowseInfo
    hOwner As Long
    pIDLRoot As Long
    pszDisplayName As String
    lpszTitle As String
    ulFlags As Long
    lpfn As Long
    lParam As Long
    iImage As Long
End Type

Function GetDirectory(Optional msg) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim bInfo As BrowseInfo
    Dim path As String
    Dim r As Long, x As Long, pos As Integer

     'Root folder = Desktop
    bInfo.pIDLRoot = 0&

     'Title in the dialog
    If IsMissing(msg) Then
        bInfo.lpszTitle = "Please select the folder of the excel files to copy."
    Else
        bInfo.lpszTitle = msg
    End If

     'Type of directory to return
    bInfo.ulFlags = &H1

     'Display the dialog
    x = SHBrowseForFolder(bInfo)

     'Parse the result
    path = Space$(512)
    r = SHGetPathFromIDList(ByVal x, ByVal path)
    If r Then
        pos = InStr(path, Chr$(0))
        GetDirectory = Left(path, pos - 1)
    Else
        GetDirectory = ""
    End If
End Function

Sub CombineFiles()
    Dim path            As String
    Dim FileName        As String
    Dim LastCell        As Range
    Dim Wkb             As Workbook
    Dim ws              As Worksheet
    Dim ThisWB          As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False


    ThisWB = ThisWorkbook.Name
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    path = GetDirectory
    FileName = Dir(path & "\*.xlsx", vbNormal)
    Do Until FileName = ""
        If FileName <> ThisWB Then
            Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=path & "\" & FileName)
            For Each ws In Wkb.Worksheets
                If ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
                Else
                    ws.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
                End If
            Next ws
            Wkb.Close False
        End If
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set Wkb = Nothing
    Set LastCell = Nothing

    Call Sort_Tabs

    Call Hide_create_tab

    Call Select_all_sheets

    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show "Enter MCR file name"


    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub


Sub Sort_Tabs()
     'declare our variables
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim iNumSheets As Integer
     'find the number of sheets to work with
    iNumSheets = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
     'turn off screen updating to prevent screen flicker
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     'work through our number of sheets
    For i = 1 To iNumSheets - 1
        For j = i + 1 To iNumSheets
             'check the name of the sheet regardless of case
            If UCase(Sheets(i).Name) > UCase(Sheets(j).Name) Then
                 'set where to move the sheet to
                Sheets(j).Move before:=Sheets(i)
            End If
             'do next sheet
        Next j
    Next i
     'let the screen update
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub Hide_create_tab()

Sheets("Create MCR").Select
ActiveSheet.Visible = False

End Sub

Sub Select_all_sheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Sheets
    If ws.Visible Then ws.Select (False)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I've fixed the code-formatting and added [vba] tag

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this page:
https://jkp-ads.com/Articles/apideclarations.asp

NB: Please make sure all code in your message is marked as such so we can easily read the code.